# Need help in theming a default view

Tags: css

**UPDATE:**

**If I give float: right it will not display in the same line. kindly view the screenshot attached. In my case it time and readmore should display in the same line.**

find the code below:

```
<div class="view-content">
<div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">
  <div class="views-field views-field-title"><span class="field-content"><a href="node/34">Test Node</a></span>  </div>  
  <div class="views-field views-field-field-description"><div class="field-content">Test Node Test Node Test Node Test Node Test Node Test </div>  </div>  
  <div class="views-field views-field-timestamp"><span class="field-content">Thursday, May 16, 2013 - 12:38</span>  </div>  
  <div class="views-field views-field-view-node"><span class="field-content"><a href="node/34">Read more</a></span>  </div>  </div>
</div>
```

**Find the current output :**

[image]

**Required Ouput :**
[image]

MY CSS:

```
.views-field-title {
  font-size: medium;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.views-field-field-description {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.views-field-timestamp {
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  color: #C60E3B;
}

.views-field-view-node {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #B2B5B6;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

What changes in css can make the required output ?

Many thanks in advance....

Comment: add `text-align :right` to `.views-field-view-node`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfect candidate for a `float:left;` and `float:right;`. You basically want something left and something right.

You can take a look at this working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DvfLG/1/). I added some control over `.view-content`, then defined  `.views-field-timestamp` to be floating at left and `.views-field-view-node` at right.

Comment: Thanks frederik. But if we write this code border-bottom is displaying ONLY for read-more field. It should display for all the content.

Comment: Then the `border-bottom` attribute should be specified for `.view-content` (the whole thing) instead of `.views-field-view-node`. I updated my Fiddle accordingly.

Comment: if you give for .view-content it will display only at the end of the div. It should display for each and every div.. That means it's in a loop.

Comment: You mean at the end of each div that has the class `view-rows` ? Try to be more specific in what you ask here so people can answer your question correctly.

Comment: Nope.. To be clear at the begining of each div it has the class views-row.

Comment: Added border-bottom at class views-row. It works.. Many Thanks for more informations and instant replies....

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/B5Q47/)

```
.views-field-timestamp {
    display:inline-block;
}

.views-field-view-node {
    display:inline-block;
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: Thanks sonu. But if we write this code border-bottom is displaying only for read-more field. In my case it should be display over all...